# Response function for digital camera pixel

Tags: image-processing, camera

To help me with doing some signal processing on an image, I'd like to model how a digital camera works.

The camera has a bunch of pixels.  What is the relationship between the value of that pixel in the resulting image, compared to the intensity of the light entering that pixel sensor?

- Is it a linear function?
- Is there some nonlinear response function?
- If it is nonlinear, how  can I recover or model that response function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, what you are asking for is called *camera response function* (CRF) and in general it is nonlinear and depends on camera device. For fixed device denote its CRF by $f$. Then $f$ maps the set of possible scene irradiances (or illuminances) $\mathcal{I}$ at a given spatial location to the set of possible pixel intensity values $\mathcal{B}$ so $f:\mathcal{I}\rightarrow \mathcal{B}$. In order to estimate $f$ you need to prepare a data set of pairs $(I_j,B_j)_{1\leq j\leq n}$ such that
$$f(I_j) = B_j$$
In practice you can use $I_j$ as raw camera outputs (for instance you may use dng format) of a given scene $S$ and $B_j$ as a pixel values (extracted from jpg image you have taken immediately after dng image) that correspond to them. Then just use any reasonable regression method.

Estimation of CRF is a subject of a large research in computer vision. Let me give you some prominent references. Since I am not expert in this area, I strongly recommend you to consult them.

[Debevec, Malik](http://www.pauldebevec.com/Research/HDR/debevec-siggraph97.pdf)

[Grossberg, Nayar](http://www1.cs.columbia.edu/CAVE/publications/pdfs/Grossberg_CVPR03.pdf)

Comment: Ahh, yes, that's exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. I am pleased that you find my answer useful.